# Может ли лечь сайт при его непрерывном обновлении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-сайт

Пишу браузер. Хочу узнать, можно ли положить *простенький сайт*, если в течение, к примеру, **10 минут с помощью цикла постоянно обновлять страницу**? Вообще можно ли таким способом довести сайт до болезненного состояния?

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, что подразумевается под словом «простенький». Какой-нибудь Sanic с пустым обработчиком на средней мощности компьютере вполне вытянет тысячи запросов в секунду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, короткий ответ на Ваш вопрос - "можно".

Правда, "лежать" сайт будет ровно столько, сколько вы его "долбите" запросами.

Дело в том, что  даже на "простеньких" сайтах некотрые страницы генерируются динамически, например, вытаскивая инфу из базы. С точки зрения человека затраты времени на это - минимальны, но по сравнению с отдачей статической страницы такая последовательность - запрос данных из базы, построение страницы, выдача страницы пользователю - довольно долгая и затратная поо ресурсам.

Так что, если Вы обнариужите на сайте такую страницу - вы смело можете попробовать его "положить".

Теперь - как с таким бороться. Во первых, существуют rate limiters - такие штуки, которые ограничивают активность слишком активных.

Во вторых, многие сайта находятся за какой тоо штукой типа cloudflare - это такой "глобальный прокси", который как раз предназначен, в частности, для защиты от DDOS - атак.

Надеюсь, этой инфы будет для Вас достаточно, чтобы продолжить дальнейший поиск самостоятельно!

Comment: Более, чем достаточно. Спасибо большое, порадовали меня, пойду добавлять эту функцию браузеру:)